# How to pipe a string to a command that expects input from stdin in one line in a bash script

Tags: bash

I have a CLI utility command that requires input from stdin to authenticate and access the endpoint, sth. like below:

```
❯ command login xxx.com username
Password:
```

How do I pass a variable as stdin to this prompt silently in one line in a bash script? I tried the below, but it didn't work. It still requires you to type in a password.

```
#!/bin/bash

PASSWORD="12345"

echo $PASSWORD | command login xxx.com username
```

❯ ./script.sh

Login...

Password:

Comment: The command is apparently reading from something other than standard input. Whether you can use some other method to provide the password depends on exactly how the command is doing the reading, and different commands do this differently. What is the command you're trying to script?

Comment: Be prepared to install and use the `expect` system. Search here for may examples. Good luck.

Comment: @GordonDavisson The command is just a CLI utility written by Python to log in a database.

Comment: The it depends on exactly how that Python script reads the password. Can you check the part of the script that does the reading?

Answer (score 1):

First, notice that `command` is a `bash` builtin.
Then, assuming you are using it just as a placeholder and that it reads from stdin

```
mycommand login xxx.com username <<<"$PASSWORD"
```

provides the content of the variable as `stdin`.

However, as mentioned in the comments you may probably need `expect` or [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) if it reads from the `tty` instead.

Comment: "mycommand" is a python utility to run from command line. I tried it out but it still requires to type in password.
```
❯ mycommand login xxx.com username <<<"$PASSWORD"
Password:
```

Comment: Because it's not reading from `stdin`, then you need expect/pexpect